# Background white when scrolling

Tags: html, css, containers, navbar, sidebar

I have navbar, sidebar and the content page.
When I scroll down, I see a background white.
There is a way to fix this? I'm new with CSS/HTML.

Here: https://i.gyazo.com/f2a18b70303b850fdd7ba6e69dfc2460.mp4

```
CSS: pastebin.com/WHNekjDW
HTML: pastebin.com/D1Cdm3Ek
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mre].

Comment: Probably the element that has the background must have the height 100% and position absolute/relative. We can't tell without a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background-color of the body - element. That's the most common way.
`body {background-color: #18181b;}`